# Overloading function with call-by-name parameter and function with by-value parameter

Tags: scala, overloading, callbyname

Why does `doSmth(() => s)` not compile?
Why does the rest of the code output "value"? Is there a way to call the second function(with call-by-name parameter)?

```
object Test {
  def main (args: Array[String]){
    lazy val s: String = ""
    doSmth(s)
    doSmth("")
    doSmth(() => s)
  }

  def doSmth(p: String): Unit = {
    println("value!")
  }
  def doSmth(p: => String): Unit = {
    println("call by name!")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works and compiles as expected:

```
def doSmth(p: String): Unit = {
  println("value!")
}
def doSmth(p: () => String): Unit = {
  println("call by name!")
}

lazy val s: String = ""
doSmth(s)
doSmth("")
doSmth(() => s)
```

Note that if you have two versions of the method, one which is by-name and one which is by-value, there is no way for Scala to know which one you mean. Instead above, the second version of the method takes a function from unit to string.

Comment: well, even with the original version of the code, `doSmth("")` outputs "value!"

Comment: One of the questions I was asking whether I could call `doSmth()` and make it output "call by name!" without changing the original function

Comment: If you have doSmth defined as taking both a call by value String and a call by reference String, then the compiler can't determine which version to execute. 

Whereas in my example, the second version of doSmth takes a function from unit to string, then you can choose to pass a string, or a function which yields a string, the compiler can tell the difference.

Comment: If the compiler was not able to determine which one to call, it would not compile.

Comment: `doSmth(() => s)` does not compile.
However, `doSmth("")` and `doSmth(s)` does compile, so compiler does not which function to call.

Comment: doSmth(() => s) does not compile because () => s is a function from Unit to s and you have not instance of doSmth which takes a function with that signature as a parameter. `=> s` and `() => s` are not the same thing.

Comment: All right, thanks! That makes sense.
However, I still do not understand, how can I make a call to
`def doSmth(p: => String): Unit = println("call by name!")`
when 
`def doSmth(p: String): Unit = println("value!")`
is in scope

Comment: Basically, you can't.  So, it's not useful to have both.